# Unable to redirect HTTP POST calls after enabling HTTPS in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am able to re-direct HTTP calls to HTTPS. But the problem is that POST requests to HTTP are re-directed as GET calls to HTTPS and they are failing with a 405 error.

Comment: Please post code to figure out the problem

Comment: https://drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/ 
I followed this link to enable HTTPS. But bumped into this problem.